# Looking to fetch data by transposing a table which has growing number of records

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, pivot

I have a table in Oracle which is like this, and I don’t know how many ‘Vendor’ is there, this keeps on growing ( but will grow around 50).
Basically same products from different Vendors are sourced. The same Product is identified by the same ‘Alias’.

| Alias | Product_ID | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc001 | V1 |
| 123 | abc002 | V2 |
| 123 | abc003 | V3 |
| 456 | abc004 | V1 |
| 456 | abc005 | V2 |
| 456 | abc006 | V3 |

I want to represent the data like this:

| Alias | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc001 | abc002 | abc003 |
| 456 | abc004 | abac005 | abc006 |

Please note that I don’t know how many vendors will get added tomorrow, so my query should work in such a way that it gives an additional column with the same query if a new vendor is added tomorrow.

I need to try this out in Oracle.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you will have 50 vendors, your "table" will grow to 50 columns. The only reason to do this kind of pivoting is for a final report (for business user consumption); but what business user is able to read and understand a table with 50 columns? What I'm saying is that the task itself is nonsensical - whoever requested it doesn't know what they are doing. Can you talk them out of it?

Comment: Also - I just edited your post (minimally) to show how to format code. Hit the Edit button and do the same to the other code fragments. Without formatting the question is unreadable.